# Check 10 GCS buckets for files

Tags: python, automation, google-cloud-storage

I need help in checking on how to implement a python code to check for files availability in 10 different GCS buckets in sequential manner if any files are available those files should be written to a file..

Any suggestions on who to implement the logic or sample code snippets will be much helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A for loop over your list of bucket. Which difficulties do you have to achieve this?

Comment: I am able to loop but would like to know how can we execute gsutil ls and gsutil stat commands through python

Answer (score 0):

Don't use gsutil in python. Use the [client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html). Here the beginning of what you want. Iterate over the bucket and it's done!!

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(<bucket-name>)
    for b in bucket.list_blobs():
        print(b.name)
        b.download_to_filename('./' + b.name)
```